# Python: Web Scraping em página dinâmica

Tags: python-3.x

Estou pesquisando sobre web scraping. Já encontrei dezenas de páginas, porém, em nenhuma delas encontrei como extrair informações de páginas dinâmicas.

Pois bem, estou tentando pegar o valor da criptomoeda LTCBRL  diretamente no site a seguir: https://br.tradingview.com/symbols/LTCBRL/

Abaixo está a foto da tela... [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A tag em que está o valor é:

```
<span class="tv-symbol-header-quote__value tv-symbol-header-quote__value--large js-symbol-last">269.97</span>
```

**Eu gostaria de apenas uma dica de como pegar o valor.**

O código fornecido pelo colega **Jones Vieira** foi:

Ele informa que para ele funcionou, porém, para mim apresente o erro na imagem abaixo.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    chrome_options = chrome_options,
    service_args = ['--verbose']
)

driver.get('https://br.tradingview.com/symbols/LTCBRL')
wait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'tv-symbol-header-quote__value'))
)

value = driver.find_element_by_class_name('tv-symbol-header-quote__value').text
print(value)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: https://scrapy.org

Comment: você esta tentando pegar o objeto que possui o valor diretamente?

Comment: @RFL sim. Estou. É aquele valor 269.99, dentro da tag <span class="tv-symbol-header-quote__value tv-symbol-header-quote__value--large js-symbol-last">269.97</span>

Comment: Já pesquisei tanto e, li em perguntas de outros usuários que pode ser a questão do javascript.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o Selenium? https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io

Comment: Já pesquisei sobre, ainda há pouco. Ainda vou precisar aprender como utilizar. Tentei pegar um código pronto apenas para teste mas não deu certo.

Comment: Se alguém me disse que a biblioteca selenium ou qualquer outra certamente funcionaria, eu a estudaria sabendo que a solução estaria lá... a questão é que já li bastante e, sem rumo me sinto perdido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta esse código, fiz aqui rápido pra testar e funcionou:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    chrome_options = chrome_options,
    service_args = ['--verbose']
)

driver.get('https://br.tradingview.com/symbols/LTCBRL')
wait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'tv-symbol-header-quote__value'))
)

value = driver.find_element_by_class_name('tv-symbol-header-quote__value').text
print(value)
```

Comment: Caro Jones Vieira. Agradeço sua atenção. O código não funcionou comigo. Eu atualizei a minha pergunta colocando o código que você informou e a imagem de erro. Agradeço!

Comment: Eu instalei o drive do chrome pelo link a seguir  
 https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads    e funcionou pelo seu código. Obrigado

Comment: Que bom que funcionou amigo. Fiz um teste em um projeto que eu já possuía o driver, por esse motivo acabei esquecendo de informar a necessidade dele.